# How to divide large numbers and what algorithm to use

Tags: algorithm, numbers

I want to manipulate really big numbers and I am trying to work with arrays. I have already implemented the multiplication operation, but now I want to implement the division operation.

I was wondering which algorithm(s) should I use? Is it possible to use the [Newton–Raphson division](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_algorithm#Newton.E2.80.93Raphson_division) algorithm or maybe should I use the algorithm that we learned in the school?

PS: I know that there are many libraries that work with big numbers, but I want to do this for practice.

Comment: when it is for practice: implement both, then compare dev effort and performance.

Answer (score 2):

These are my favorite algorithms I use:

1. **Binary division**
   Look here: http://courses.cs.vt.edu/~cs1104/BuildingBlocks/divide.030.html
   This is what you should start with. It's not that slow and it is simple. Do not forget to properly test your `+, -, <<, >>` operations before you start. They should work flawlessly on any given input
2. **Division by half the bits arithmetics**
   Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19381045/2521214
   With little tweaking you can adapt it to arrays. Uses `+, -, *, /, %`. If you code it properly should be much faster then Binary division.
3. **approximation of division**
   Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18398246/2521214
   Or for some speed up of x^2, x*y here: [Fast bignum square computation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18465326/2521214)
   This is more suited for floating/fixed point division. It's a little bit harder to understand, but the speed and accuracy is worth the while. Also, there are many other approximation algorithms out there, So google!