# Calculate binary division

Tags: binary

I want to calculate 12938 divide 8192 using shifts.
First I tried to convert 12938 to binary, and my problem is how to divide by 8192 using shifts.

The numbers are so big, I got a little bit confused. Please help me to figure out the right answer. Many thanks.

Comment: integer division, or fractional?    8192 is exactly 2 ^ 13, so a right shift by thirteen will give you the integer result.

Comment: What programming language are you using. What have you tried?

Comment: The right answer is 1?

Comment: on integers yes ... see [What algorithm should I use for high-performance large integer division?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32945407/2521214)