# Generating lookup table for arctan computation

Tags: c++, math

I have seen many implementations for this but I got this new idea about which I couldn't be sure. So I need an opinion here.

The idea is that instead of looking up the table for `arctan(gy/gx)`, look for `1/gx` in one table and multiply the result with `gy`. Then lookup for `arctan`. The reason for doing so is to reduce hardware cost as division is more expensive than multiplication. But the limitation is that I can have a `maximum of 10 address bits`. Whereas, multiplication will give me twice the number of bits in `gx`. `gx` itself is 8 bits. If I right shift `gy*(1/gx)` by 6 bits to get a 10 bit address,

What could be the degree of error?

Comment: Hint: Some values are more useful than others. Only keep the useful ones.

Comment: if you use 1/gx lookup table you will probably loose some precision (hope you have floating point not fixed one). also what division for FP you use? some approximation approaches are comparable with the lookup table runtime like this one http://stackoverflow.com/a/18398246/2521214 of course if you do not have fast multiplication then lookup table is better for you ...

Comment: What is the range of gx and gy? In addition, how much does a multiplication cost relatively to division on your target machine?

Comment: Also, are gx and gy integers?

Comment: gx and gy are integers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note you only need to consider the case when `gy > gx` as `arctan(gy/gx)=90-arctan(gx/gy)` (assuming we are working in degrees in positive coordinate). This might reduce you errors with division.