# Non-Restoring Division for Floating Point

Tags: math, floating-point, hardware, verilog, division

I have found details about the non-restoring division algorithm, but from what I found it assumes that the dividend is greater than the divisor. Does this have to be true?

I am asking because I want to use the algorithm for designing a floating point division unit in hardware.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the algorithm used

- anyway you can easily shift mantisa's to match this condition
- first shift before division
- and then just add to exponent of the result after division
- for example how it is done look here [iterative FPU divider](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18398246/2521214) with similar conditions

Comment: @starbox heh just realized it is your question :) anyway if you are reffering to that algorithm from mine answer then yes it is true you have to ensure both conditions otherwise the algo will not work properly.