# Division algorithm with decimal bignum

Tags: algorithm

EDIT: I rebased my bignum class to use `std::bitset` and I just implemented long division fine. I just didn't know any class to store bits. (like `std::bitset`)

I'm making a bignum class with `std::string` to use decimal characters as internal representation. I tried implementing division with a simple algorithm:

`while N ≥ D do
    N := N - D
end
return N`

And of course it was slow. I tried implementing long division but that was too hard to do with decimal characters.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do they still teach ["long division"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_division) in primary school? Or is everyone dependent on electronics these days?

Comment: Bitwise operations can work just fine with a bignum class

Comment: Which Bignum class? Have you read the standard literature? Could you point out what you've researched so far in an edit to your question? Why would bitwise operators not work for your number representation? Why would you be the one to implement division for a numerical type for which almost certainly a competent library exists?

Comment: Hey, I said "I'm making a Bignum class" And, I didn't knew Bitwise operators can work with it

Comment: That algorithm looks more like modulo than (integer) division. Also, what language are you using, what "Bignum" class do you use, and where is your code? What is the data type of `N` and `D`?

Comment: @MarcusMüller In the given context, what exactly would you consider 'the standard literature'?

Comment: [numerical recipes](http://www.nr.com/), for example. More importantly than that, whatever library/language/textbook minary took his bignum type from.

Comment: The bignum of yours is integer,fixed point or floating point type? for integer and fixed point I recommend binary division for floating point some iteration algorithm is usually better like Newton–Raphson division or http://stackoverflow.com/a/18398246/2521214 see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_algorithm for more algos. PS your code compute just the reminder if you want the actual divison you need to add counter how many times the loop was executed

Comment: If stuff above is too much for you then you can try to use binary search (no need for bit operations) you need just `+,*,<=`

Comment: This question was based on my old version which were based on `std::string` with decimal characters (I know it was a lazy solution! I just didn't know a class like `std::bitset` when I posted this question). Now I rebased my project to use `std::bitset` and now I just implemented binary division fine.

Comment: @minary you may be interested in this [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_algorithm#Large-integer_methods).

Comment: @Rishav Thanks but I already solved this problem by using `std::bitset`. But thanks for replying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of subtracting D very often you could try to find the highest value of the form 
D^2n and sub this. Than repeat that steps with the remaining value until the remaining is less than D.

**Pseudocode**

```
0 result=0
1 powerOfD = D
2 while (powerOfD*powerOfD<N)
3   powerOfD=powerOfD*powerOfD
4 result = result+powerOfD/D, N=N-powerOfD;
5 if(N>D) 
6   goto 1
7 return result
```

Example  31/3   (N=31, D=3)

```
0 result=0
1 powerD = 3;
2 3*3 < 31   TRUE
3   powerOfD= 3*3;
2 9*9 < 31   FALSE
4 result=0+9/3; N=31 - 9
5 22> 3   TRUE
6   goto 1
1 powerD = 3
2 3*3 < 22  TRUE
3   powerOfD= 3*3;
2 9*9 < 31   FALSE
4 result=3+9/3; N=22 - 9
5 13> 3   TRUE
6   goto 1
1 powerD = 3
2 3*3 < 13  TRUE
3   powerOfD= 3*3;
2 9*9 < 31   FALSE
4 result=6+9/3; N=13 - 9
5 4> 3   TRUE
6   goto 1
1 powerD = 3
2 3*3 < 4 ALSE
4 result=9+3/3; N=4-3
5 1> 3   FALSE
7 return 10
```

Comment: What is the significance of `result`? Can you please show the steps for 31/3?

Comment: I fixed a problem in the algorithm and added the requested example. 'result' is the devision result 31/3=10 remains = 1 (stored in N)

Comment: Thanks for taking may comment seriously (: and excruciatingly to the letter :).

Comment: @greybeard: Your comment stuck me to an error in the algorithm and so it lead to a simpler and now working version. So your comment was very productive.