# How to detect exponential growth in time series table?

Tags: python-3.x, math, time-series, classification, python-module

Let's assume I have a table with columns datetime and volume for the search query "instagram".

[image: Graph Image]

[Google Trends](https://trends.google.com/trends/explore?date=now%207-d&geo=US-CA-803&q=instagram)

Is there any ready python modules that would spot time interval of exponential growth?

Comment: Fourrier transform of your time series can give you the frequencies and the period (the time interval you're looking for) is equal to 1/freq.
I'm sure there are plenty of python module for fourrier transform.

Comment: why not code it yourself? see [estimate complexity from time measurements](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64784308/2521214) ... so you pick part of the graph and check which complexity it has ... to pick parts you can use crossing of some y value or FFT to determine offset and frequency ... then chose half periods ... If you want really just exponential growth then just test few "consequent" (with some gap) values against it and check whole interval something like sliding average where you move the N consequent points positions along the curve and check ...