# Arithmetic with base 256 number system

Tags: c, algorithm, math, biginteger

I am working on a project right now where I need to perform calculations for numbers with base 256. I am reading bytes of a file and storing it in an array of `uint8_t` (a.k.a `unsigned char` or `BYTE`). The largest supported number data type doesn't satisfy the needs of my project. So the array of bytes is acting like a custom length/size data type (`BigInt`).

I now need to perform arithmetic on it like: `-1, /2, %2`.

For example this is how addition looks like to demonstrate how my numbers should work:

```
9   + 1 = (10)
99  + 1 = (100)
255 + 1 = (1)+(0)<<8
255 + 2 = (1)+(1)<<8
```

Note: First one's is 10 as in 10 is occupying 1 digit whereas the third one is 1  0 as in it's occupying 2 digits. Also I cant convert them to integers because I have to deal with **huge** numbers.

I am racking my brain trying to think of ways to implement this in C but to no avail.

My code so far:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdint.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef uint8_t BYTE;
BYTE buffer[1000000000];

void n(){
    printf("\n");
}

int main()
{
    uint32_t  x;
    x = 0; 
    int _len,y;
    char * test    = "test.bin";
    FILE * inptr = fopen(test,"rb");
    uint32_t i=0;
    while(fread(&buffer[i],1,1,inptr));
}
```

Comment: `9 + 1` is not `10` in this system. You need `256` distinct "digits" for representing it.

Comment: I do not understand, what your problem is. You can be sure that we understand how arithmetics of the non 10 bases works. You did not show any code. Ask when you have something ready.

Comment: see [Cant make value propagate through carry](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26603589/2521214) just instead of `DWORD` change to `BYTE` and update the bit-masks and shifts accordingly

Comment: Consider your arrays as polynomials (with x == 256). You can apply the same algorithms then as you would do with polynomial arithmetic. Only: you need to consider overflows!

Comment: @EugeneSh is right. think about what happen in base 16 (which should be more familiar to you) `9+1=A`

Comment: He should add something on the beginning of his number to show whish number has what base for example @. Then @9@ + @1@ = @10@ or @255@ + @1@ = @1@@0@

Comment: @DavideSpataro @EugeneSh. Consider `(9)+(1) = (10)`, `(255) + (2) = (1)(1)`, so your 256 digits are the values 0-255 placed in parentheses...

Comment: @Aconcagua Right. If that is what the OP meant, then I'll amend  my comment. BTW, `(255) + (1) = (1)(0)`

Comment: @Aconcagua yes, and I think that the space between `1` and `0` in `255+1= 1 0` was supposed to show that.  Find it very confusing though. Parens would have been appreciated :D

Comment: @EugeneSh. Intended to take first and last example, so actually would have been (2) instead of (1)... Luckily you spotted in time, so I could adjust my comment...

Comment: @EugeneSh. https://pastebin.com/V1wxVRuB Here's my code. I do need distinct digits, I tried displaying them as characters but only there are a lot of unprintable ascii characters. Also, the first 10 got stored as 00001010 whereas second 1  0 got stored as 00000001 00000000.

Comment: @rjpj1998 Yeah, as commented you representation is fine, just needed some clarification.

Comment: @PeterJ https://pastebin.com/V1wxVRuB heres my code.

Comment: @Spektre I am new at working with large integers and I don't understand what you are saying.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Could you help with me to where I went wrong that I am getting downvoted?

Comment: I would guess that the downvotes are caused by not presenting any of your work in the question and not stating clearly what the problem is.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Cool.

Comment: @DavideSpataro and EugeneSh. surely the 256 digit values required can only be 0 to 255, so the `9+1=10` was correct. OP did say that is not the same as `1 0`.

Comment: @WeatherVane The discussion above have clarified it. If you consider `10` as a "digit" and not a "two digit number", that would be fine.

Comment: @DavideSpataro My bad.

Comment: You can't seriously expect to need billion-digit numbers.

Comment: See [Arbitrary-precision arithmetic Explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1218149/1468366).

Comment: @spektre i really just want to perform some calculations on extremely large numbers. However i do plan on looking at the implementation of alu and the carry flag because they were plastered over all other answers when i tried googling my problem.

Comment: @stark i do infact need like to operate values like 2^1000000000.

Comment: @mvg i am looking into it now.

Comment: @rjpj1998 ALU is the basic stuff you should build your operations on ... In pure C/C++ you do  not have access to carry flag which make impossible to chain operations... but you can use 16 bit variables to do 8 bit addition and extract the 8th bit which is carry ... to simulate ALU.  also `2^1000000000` is not the same as yours `256^1000000000` !!! you should use array size `N=1000000000/8` or even better dynamic arrays ... as your current number is taking 1GB of memory

Comment: @Spektre Can I not utilize gmp to perform my task? Also you are right it's actually 256^1000000000.

Comment: @Spektre Also I just need modulus,subtract and divide.

Comment: @Spektre I am working on a personal project.

Comment: @Spektre I cant afford to  work with strings. Using strings will make my program eat up much more memory.

Comment: However I can display them directly in hex using the hex specifier when needed.

Comment: I dont have to print it man. I just need to process it and write the processed info into another file.

Comment: I know that. First i plan to test my program with relatively small files like 1mb.

Comment: @Spektre I need to process quite a lot of big ints but not the way you think. I get smaller bigints from the first bigint. which then gives me smaller big ints. Till the point that they can be written using a single byte or sometimes a 4 byte integer.

Comment: @spektre i need to perform modulus by 2,division by 2 and subtraction by 1

Comment: @Spektre This is exactly what I was after! I can verify this as an answer if you submit this comment as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you have power of 2 operations which can be easily converted to bit operations... no bigint lib is needed for such triviality. Let assume you got number

```
const int n=1000000000; // number size in bytes
BYTE x[n]; // number bytes let num[0] be LSW (least signifficant Word)
```

So the operations involved are:

1. **mod: `y = x%2 = x&1`**

   this is `O(1)`

   ```
   BYTE y = x[0]&1;
   ```

   result is single bit so no need to store it as bigint
2. **div: `y = x/2 = x>>1`**

   this is `O(n)` and the result is also bigint so

   ```
   int i;
   BYTE y[n]; // result
   BYTE cy; // carry flag
   for (cy=0,i=n-1;i>=0;i--) // process all words from MSW to LSW
    {
    y[i] = ((x[i]>>1)&0x7F) | cy; // bitshifted word + last carry
    cy = (x[i]<<7)&0x80; // carry is shifted out lsb of word shifted to msb position
    }
   ```
3. **dec: `y=x-1`**

   this is `O(n)` and the result is also bigint so

   ```
   int i;
   BYTE y[n]; // result
   BYTE cy; // carry flag
   for (cy=1,i=0;(i<n)&&(cy);i++) // process all words from LSW to MSW
    {
    y[i] = (x[i]-cy)&0xFF; // y[i] = sbc x[i],0
    cy = (x[i]==0x00); // carry
    }
   ```

Hope I did not make some silly syntax error or something as I coded this directly into here...

Both `O(n)` operations can be done in-place you just need to buffer actual `x[i]` value or compute carry before `x[i]` change and buffer old carry

In your case I would use 32bit (DWORD) or 64bit (QWORD) instead of 8bit (BYTE) that will boost the speed as the **ALU** on most computers is `32` or `64` bit anyway

If you're interested in implementing more of the bigint stuff see:

- [Cant make value propagate through carry](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26603589/2521214)
- [Fast bignum square computation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18465326/2521214)
- [Floating Point Divider Hardware Implementation Details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18398246/2521214)
- [Building a logarithm function in C without using float type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42108287/2521214)
- [Schönhage-Strassen multiplication using NTT](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18577076/2521214)

**[Edit1] `dec` for MSW first**

```
int i;
BYTE y[n]; // result
BYTE cy; // carry flag
for (cy=1,i=n-1;(i>=0)&&(cy);i--) // process all words from LSW to MSW
 {
 y[i] = (x[i]-cy)&0xFF; // y[i] = sbc x[i],0
 cy = (x[i]==0x00); // carry
 }
```

**and in-place:**

```
int i;
BYTE cy; // carry flag
for (cy=1,i=n-1;(i>=0)&&(cy);i--) // process all words from LSW to MSW
 {
 x[i] = (x[i]-cy)&0xFF; // y[i] = sbc x[i],0
 if (x[i]==0xFF) cy=1; // carry
 }
```

Comment: Hey, I am having problem with subtraction. First for me x[0] is the most significant number. So I changed i=0 to i= len-1 and i<len to i>=0. This is only working for 2 digit numbers. Could you help?

Comment: for(i =len-1 ;i>=0;i--)
 {
  if (buffer[i]!=0)
  {
   buffer[i] = buffer[i]-1;
   if (i<(len-1))
   {
    for (j=i+1;j<len;j++)
    {
     buffer[j] = 255;
    }
   }
   else
   {
    break;
   }
  }

Comment: @rjpj1998 hi I added the implementation of `y=x-1` with MSW first encoding as edit1