# Round to the nearest power of two

Tags: algorithm

Is there a one line expression (possibly boolean) to get the nearest `2^n` number for a given integer?

Example: 5,6,7 must be 8.

Comment: "One line" in a programming language?  Or mathematically?

Comment: This is roughly equivalent to [counting leading zeros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/376840/trailing-leading-zero-count-for-a-byte), since you're interested in the first non-zero bit.

Comment: What language are you trying to do this in? What have you tried?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/466204/rounding-off-to-nearest-power-of-2

Comment: In your example, the nearest power of two for 5 is actually 4 (or 2^2). For 6, the answer is ambiguous (may be either 2^2 or 2^3). Can you specify the question a little further?

Comment: @ Gerco Dries: It's legitimate to use a logarithmic scale when considering the nearest power of 2 to a number.  On that basis 6 is closer to 2^3 than 2^2.  Not saying you are wrong, just an alternate view point.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Given an integer, how do I find the next largest power of two using bit-twiddling?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1322510/given-an-integer-how-do-i-find-the-next-largest-power-of-two-using-bit-twiddlin)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rounding up to nearest power of 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/466204/rounding-up-to-nearest-power-of-2)

Answer (score 33):

Round up to the next higher power of two: see [bit-twiddling hacks](http://graphics.stanford.edu/%7Eseander/bithacks.html#RoundUpPowerOf2).

In C:

```c
unsigned int v; // compute the next highest power of 2 of 32-bit v

v--;
v |= v >> 1;
v |= v >> 2;
v |= v >> 4;
v |= v >> 8;
v |= v >> 16;
v++;
```

Comment: Because it decrements, then sets all bits below its most significant bit to 1, then it increments.

Comment: Becareful when using signed int.  Values > 0x4000_0000 will return 0x8000_0000.

Comment: Input values > 0x8000_0000 will return 0.

Comment: Incidentally, you can right shift by one place at the end to get the next lowest power of 2.

Comment: @JasonS you mean the decrement sets all bits below its least significant bit to 1

Answer (score 22):

I think you mean next nearest 2^n number. You can do a log on the mode 2 and then determine next integer value out of it.

For java, it can be done like:

```
Math.pow(2, Math.ceil(Math.log(x)/Math.log(2)))
```

Comment: A Python version: `from math import ceil, log; closest = lambda x: int(ceil(log(x) / log(2)))`

Answer (score 11):

Since the title of the question is "Round to the nearest power of two", I thought it would be useful to include a solution to that problem as well.

```c
int nearestPowerOfTwo(int n)
{
    int v = n; 

    v--;
    v |= v >> 1;
    v |= v >> 2;
    v |= v >> 4;
    v |= v >> 8;
    v |= v >> 16;
    v++; // next power of 2

    int x = v >> 1; // previous power of 2

    return (v - n) > (n - x) ? x : v;
}
```

It basically finds both the previous and the next power of two and then returns the nearest one.

Comment: Would not be more efficient to compute first `v` and then for `x` use `x = v >> 1`?

Comment: You're so right. I integrated your suggestion in my answer. Thank you

Answer (score 6):

Your requirements are a little confused, the nearest power of 2 to 5 is 4.  If what you want is the next power of 2 up from the number, then the following *Mathematica* expression does what you want:

```
2^Ceiling[Log[2, 5]] => 8
```

From that it should be straightforward to figure out a one-liner in most programming languages.

Answer (score 6):

For next power of two up from a given integer `x`

`2^(int(log(x-1,2))+1)`

or alternatively (if you do not have a `log` function accepting a *base* argument

`2^(int(log(x-1)/log(2))+1)`

Note that this does not work for x < 2

Answer (score 2):

This can be done by right shifting on the input number until it becomes 0 and keeping the count of shifts. This will give the position of the most significant 1 bit. Getting 2 to the power of this number will give us the next nearest power of 2.

```java
public int NextPowerOf2(int number) {
    int pos = 0;
    
    while (number > 0) {
        pos++;
        number = number >> 1; 
    }
    return (int) Math.pow(2, pos);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For rounding up to the nearest power of 2 in Java, you can use this. Probably faster for longs than the bit-twiddling stuff mentioned in other answers.

```java
static long roundUpToPowerOfTwo(long v) {
  long i = Long.highestOneBit(v);
  return v > i ? i << 1 : i;
}
```

Comment: For Java this should be the correct answer. While it does the same bit-twiddling under the hood, the implementation is annotated as `@HotSpotIntrinsicCandidate` which means that it can be replaced by a faster native method if the architecture allows for it.

Answer (score 1):

Round n to the next power of 2 in one line in Python:

`next_power_2 = 2 ** (n - 1).bit_length()`

Answer (score 0):

Modified for VBA. `NextPowerOf2_1` doesn't seem to work. So I used loop method. Needed a shift right bitwise operator though.

```vb
Sub test()
    NextPowerOf2_1(31)
    NextPowerOf2_2(31)
    NextPowerOf2_1(32)
    NextPowerOf2_2(32)
End Sub

Sub NextPowerOf2_1(ByVal number As Long) ' Does not work
    Debug.Print 2 ^ (Int(Math.Log(number - 1) / Math.Log(2)) + 1)
End Sub

Sub NextPowerOf2_2(ByVal number As Long)
    Dim pos As Integer
    pos = 0
    While (number > 0)
        pos = pos + 1
        number = shr(number, 1)
    Wend
    
    Debug.Print 2 ^ pos
End Sub
Function shr(ByVal Value As Long, ByVal Shift As Byte) As Long
    Dim i As Byte
    shr = Value
    If Shift > 0 Then
        shr = Int(shr / (2 ^ Shift))
    End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a basic version for Go

```golang
// Calculates the next highest power of 2.
// For example: n = 15, the next highest power of 2 would be 16
func NearestPowerOf2(n int) int {
    v := n
    v--
    v |= v >> 1
    v |= v >> 2
    v |= v >> 4
    v |= v >> 8
    v |= v >> 16
    v++
    return v
}
```